# GLMM and factor significance

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, p-value

In my area of studies, scientists and reviewers often look at the results of GLMM in the context of ANOVA, so they demand a single p-value for the whole factor (not its levels). I read a lot about the idea of not using p-values, but still, in many simple cases, it is just convenient and needed (to have a clear answer). Even right now, I am working on the mixed model with one random and one fixed factor with 6 levels. How can I solve a general demand of presenting an answer if the influence of the factor is significant or not? I see from lme4 and lmerTest that some of the levels are different from the reference level, some not, but it is still not what I need to present.

Answer (score 0):

To just test for the significance of a single fixed effect, you can run a hierarchical F-test which compares the model containing your factor of interest with a more parsimonous model that does not contain the factor. This gives you the desired p-value for the whole factor.

Example code

```
library(lme4)

m0<- lmer(dv ~ a + (1|random intercept))
m1<- lmer(dv ~ a + b + (1| random intercept))
anova(m0, m1)
```